# mvc genericly binding byte[] properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I've tried using a custom model binder but my request.files is not populated. IN forms collection, the input of type file for the byte[] property is populated by file name only.

```html
<input id="collection[@index].@p.Name" name="collection[@index].@p.Name" type="file" />
```

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace male.services.mvc.Binders
{
  public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
  {

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      if (bindingContext.ModelType.GetProperties().Any(o => o.PropertyType == typeof(byte[])))
      {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        foreach (var pi in bindingContext.ModelType.GetProperties().Where(o => o.PropertyType == typeof(byte[])))
        {
          // can't access any property in the parameters that gives me my file input or my stream
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
      }
      else
      {
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This will allow me to go straight from html file inputs to EF models without resorting to hand-crafting a file argument for each model type and property type which needs it. ([Aint nobody got time for that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFEoMO0pc7k))

In order for a form to post files, it must have the enctype attribute:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ... />
```

Once that is done, the file can be accessed via `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Files`

**UPDATE - Working Example**

*Note: You don't need the `Regex` stuff if you aren't trying to bind a collection. You also don't need the `EndsWith`, you can just use `==`*

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace male.services.mvc.Binders
{
  public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
  {

    HttpRequestBase request;

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
      return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
      if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(byte[]))
      {
        var key = request.Files.AllKeys.SingleOrDefault(o => o.EndsWith($"].{propertyDescriptor.Name}"));
        var fileIndex = Regex.Match(key, @"\[(.*)\]").Groups[1].Value;
        var modelIndex = Regex.Match(bindingContext.ModelName, @"\[(.*)\]").Groups[1].Value;
        if(fileIndex == modelIndex)
        {
          HttpPostedFileWrapper httpPostedFile = (HttpPostedFileWrapper)request.Files[request.Files.AllKeys.SingleOrDefault(o => o.EndsWith(propertyDescriptor.Name))];
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
            httpPostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, ms.ToArray());
          }
        }
      }
      else
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
  }
}
```